# How do I get advanced date control for SSRS Reports which allows me to select year?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, datechooser

Is there a better way to allow us to scan back a year at a time in addition to a month at a time rather than just only a month at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You could add **Year** & **Month** parameters to your report, which are used by the date control to get a starting point. 
For example, Give the user a list of possible years to choose from and a list of months. Use these in conjunction with '/01' to set the default for you date control parameter.

This will mean extra work & paramters, but it will solve your dilemma.